# Best implementation of turn-based access on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to implement a 2-player turn-based game with a  GAE backend. The first thing this game requires is a very simple match making system that operates like this:

1. User A asks the backend for a match. The back ends tells him to come back later
2. User B asks the backend for a match. He will be matched with A.
3. User C asks the backend for a match. The back ends tells him to come back later
4. User D asks the backend for a match. He will be matched with C.
5. and so on...

*(edit: my assumption is that if I can figure this one out, most other operation i a turn based game can use the same implementation)*

This can be done quite easily in [Apple Gamecenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW1) and [Xbox Live](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29197), however I would rather implement this on an open and platform independent backend like GAE. After some research, I have found the following options for a GAE implementation:

- use memcache. However, there is no guarantee that the memcache is synchronized across different instances. I did some tests and could actually see match request disappearing due to memcache mis-synchronization.
- Harden memcache with Sharding Counters. This does not always solve the multiple instance problem and mayabe results in high memcache quota usage.
- Use memcache with Compare and Set. Does not solve the multiple instance problem when used as a mutex.
- task queues. I have no idea how to use these but someone mentioned as a possible solution. However, I am afraid that queues will eat me GAE quota very quickly.
- push queues. Same as above.
- transaction. Same as above. Also probably very expensive.
- channels. Same as above. Also probably very expensive.

Given that the match making is a very basic operation in online games, I cannot be the first one encountering this. Hence my questions:

- Do you know of any **safe** mechanism for match making?
- If multiple solutions exist, which is the **cheapest** (in terms of GAE quota usage) solution?

Comment: You said "use memcache. However, there is no guarantee that the memcache is synchronized across different instances."  Where did you see that?  AFAIK it is, however nothing is guarunteed to be present in memcache, it is after all a cache, and docs are pretty explicit about cache eviction, hence soleyly relying on it for matching would be problematic, but not for the reason you state.

Comment: I'm thinking on implementing turn-based game on GAE and I so far plan to use transactions for synchronization and channels for client push updates. In your case user A would be added to the data store as an "unmatched" user (within a transaction) and left with a "channel" to listen to. Then in response to user B request servlet will read list of "unmatched" players and will match B to A and update record so that A is no longer unmatched (all within a transaction). Finally user A will receive a push notification through the channel that he has got a match.

Comment: as Tim notes, a *single* memcache instance is shared across all different application instances. I'd suggest using a backend for this, but as you want it in the free quota allowance that won't be possible (you only get ~9 hours a day).

Comment: @TimHoffman is correct, memcache is not guaranteed to hold the correct values even without the coherency problems.

Comment: You might consider investigating Prospective Search https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/overview  from the docs - "Prospective search is a querying service that allows your application to match search queries against real-time data streams. For every document presented, prospective search returns the ID of every registered query that matches the document."     You could consider creating match records, and as new users ask for a match new records are created and matched that way.  Just a thought.  - this could possibly mean no backends for matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using a cron tasks in a scheme like this:

```
define MatchRequest:
    requestor = db.StringProperty()
    opponent = db.StringProperty(default = '')
```

User A asks for a match, a MatchRequest entity is created with A as the requestor and the opponent blank.
User A polls to see when the opponent field has been filled.
User B asks for a match, a MatchRequest entity is created with B as as the requestor.
User B pools to see when the opponent field has been filled.

A cron job that runs every 20 seconds? or so runs:

1. Grab all MatchRequest where opponent == ''
2. Make all appropriate matches
3. Put all the MatchRequests as a transaction

Now when A and B poll next they will see that they they have an opponent.

According to the [GAE docs on crons](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) free apps can have up to 20 free cron tasks. The computation required for these crons for a small amount of users should be small.

This would be a **safe** way but I'm not sure if it is the **cheapest** way. It's also pretty easy to implement.

Comment: A cron job that runs every 20 seconds probably requires a dedicated instance given the slow start time of jobs. Still, I think you are into something. The match request table that is write only and then a separate task that joins them and writes them to a Matched table, that would probably solve most (but not all) synchronization problems.